# Java Compare Arrays Containing Characters

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so what i want to do is compare certain characters of the arrays and return a false or true. I first convert some strings to Arrays, date is already converted to string.

```
    char[] serialArray = SerialKey.toCharArray();

    char[] macArray = MacAddress.toCharArray();

    char[] dateArray = date.toCharArray();
```

For example i want to compare the serialArray[2] with the dateArray[0] and see if these are the same.

But it seems that

```
    if(serialArray[2].equals(dateArray[0]))
    {

    }
```

won't work. I get char cannot be dereferenced.

Thank you

Comment: Any specific reason you dont want to use "==" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For characters, equality is done via the `==` operator. Strings are objects, so have the `equals` method.

```
if(serialArray[2] == dateArray[0])
{

}
```

If you create a `Character` object, that will have an `equals` method, but it's unnecessary:

```
if(new Character(serialArray[2]).equals(new Character(dateArray[0])))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since their type is `char` and not `String`

```
 if(serialArray[2] ==  dateArray[0] )
    {

    }
```

You might confused with char and String.

Answer (score 0):

char[] defines an array of 'char' which is primitive type and not Object type, hence you have to use '==' to compare it. If you want to compare using '.equals()' declare your array as `Character[]`.